# Excel VBA insert formula with a variable into a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to insert a formula using VBA into a cell but I always get a run-time error 1004. Code looks like this:

```
Sub save_data()

Dim source As Worksheet
Dim list As Worksheet
Dim nextRow As Integer
Dim nextId As Integer
Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date, randDatum As Date, dateOfBirth As Date

startDate = "17/6/2018"
randDate = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(startDate, Date)

Set source = Worksheets("Add user")
Set list = Worksheets("Users")

nextRow = list.Range("A" & list.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
nextId = list.Range("A" & list.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value + 1
dateOfBirth = source.Range("F24").Value

list.Cells(nextRow, 1).Value = nextId
list.Cells(nextRow, 2).Value = source.Range("F4").Value
list.Cells(nextRow, 3).Value = source.Range("F6").Value
list.Cells(nextRow, 4).Value = source.Range("F8").Value
list.Cells(nextRow, 5).Value = source.Range("F10").Value
list.Cells(nextRow, 6).Value = source.Range("F12").Value
list.Cells(nextRow, 7).Value = source.Range("F14").Value
list.Cells(nextRow, 8).Value = source.Range("F16").Value
list.Cells(nextRow, 9).Value = source.Range("F18").Value
list.Cells(nextRow, 10).Value = source.Range("F20").Value
list.Cells(nextRow, 11).Value = source.Range("F22").Value
list.Cells(nextRow, 12).Value = source.Range("F24").Value
list.Range("M" & nextRow).Formula = "=ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(" & dateOfBirth & ",TODAY(),1),0)"
list.Cells(nextRow, 14).Value = Date
list.Cells(nextRow, 15).Value = randDate
list.Cells(nextRow, 16).Value = Date - randDate
list.Cells(nextRow, 16).Value = "=TODAY()"

End Sub
```

I have tried Formula and FormulaLocal but result is always the same.

Comment: What is the value of the `dateOfBirth` variable when you break the code at this line? What is the "result" that is "always the same"? An error? Unexpected answer? Something else?

Comment: Did you set `source` and `list` correcly?

Comment: Value of the dateOfBirth is 6.7.2011. The resul is that I always get run-time error. And yes source and list are set corretly, it works in other parts of the code.

Comment: I changed the semi-colons to commas and the formula worked

Comment: Is `nextRow` defined, and assigned a value? Also, which run-time error do you get?

Comment: Please Debug your code (via Stepping `F8` key) and return to us with which line was highlighted and the exact error. My money would be on the `list.Range` line

Comment: Additionally, your code is incomplete (eg. `nextRow` is lacking definition). We can't correct your code, if we don't know what it looks like!

Comment: Not sure if this would throw a `1004`, but you're using `FormulaLocal`. If your Excel version is using any language other than English, this will throw an error

Comment: I tried changing semicolons to commas and still error. NextRow has value assigned. I get run-time error 1004. Application-defined or object-defined error. Problem is with list.Range line. Everything else works as it should.

Comment: We ***need*** to see the full code. Your formula appears fine. Perhaps `nextrow` is populated with a value <1 or >1,048,576. Can only guess with this partial code

Comment: Or at least go through the code using `F8` and tell us the values of `source`, `list`, `nextRow` and `dateOfBirth` and how you dim'd these variables.

Comment: `6.7.2011` Is probably a text string and not a date.

Comment: No, its a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the date of birth is 6.7.2011.

That means, using your formula:

`.Formula = "=ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(" & dateOfBirth & ",TODAY(),1),0)"`

it will create the formula:

`=ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(6.7.2011,TODAY(),1),0)`

Can you see the issue now?

Try using:

`.Formula = "=ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(" & dateOfBirth * 1 & ",TODAY(),1),0)"`

This will create the formula:

`=ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(40730,TODAY(),1),0)`

..which while looking a little strange, should give you the right answer and not error.